# Deny port redirection based on source IP - firewalld

Tags: linux, centos, firewall, centos7, firewalld

I'm trying to **forward a port to an external IP** using `firewall-cmd`, but I need to **deny access from certain ips**.

---

To setup a port-forward of port `55500`, I use:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-forward-port=port=55500:proto=tcp:toport=55500:toaddr=2.2.2.2
```

Which works fine, and users connecting to port `55500` are successfully redirected to `2.2.2.2` , but, as mentioned previously, I need to deny access to users coming from `1.1.1.1/24`, for that I tried:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address='1.1.1.1/24' reject"
```

or :

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 source address=1.1.1.1/24 port port=55500 protocol=tcp reject'
```

or:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=drop --add-source=1.1.1.1/24
```

But none of the commands above (all followed by `firewall-cmd --reload`) worked, and users connecting to port `55500` from `1.1.1.1` still get redirected to `2.2.2.2`.

---

How can I deny the port redirection based on the source IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It didn't work before because I missed  `--permanent`.
The following command denies any port redirection from users coming from `1.1.1.1/24`:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=drop --permanent --add-source=1.1.1.1/24
firewall-cmd --reload
```